# Pintar un pixel con WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

Estoy tratando de implementar el [algoritmo de Bresenham](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Bresenham) para pintar lineas con [WebGL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL).

Quiero pintar pixel por pixel de la línea gracias a este algoritmo.

Mi pregunta es, **¿hay alguna forma de pintar un pixel en WebGL?**

Comment: Respondo de oídas... con WebGL creo que no puedes pintar pixeles directamente, pero lo puedes "simular" pintando cuadrados "muy pequeños", pero no me hagas mucho caso... Si solo es para probar el algoritmo, mejor usa canvas.

Comment: Eso eh hecho por lo pronto, ahora estoy probando el algoritmo de punto medio para circunferencias y tengo problemas :S

Comment: Utilizando un fragment/pixel shader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesitas `webgl` para esto. El canvas trae funciones para representación en dos dimensiones ya que el citado algoritmo no dibuja en profundidad (solo estas dibujando puntos).

Para dibujar un punto usa

```
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```

Rellena el pixel en x, y

Este sería el algoritmo

```js
function Bresenham(ctx, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  var x, y, dx, dy, p, incE, incNE, stepx, stepy;
  dx = (x1 - x0);
  dy = (y1 - y0);

  if (dy < 0) {
    dy = -dy;
    stepy = -1;
  } else {
    stepy = 1;
  }

  if (dx < 0) {
    dx = -dx;
    stepx = -1;
  } else {
    stepx = 1;
  }

  x = x0;
  y = y0;
  ctx.fillRect(x0, y0, 1, 1);

  if (dx > dy) {
    p = 2 * dy - dx;
    incE = 2 * dy;
    incNE = 2 * (dy - dx);
    while (x != x1) {
      x = x + stepx;
      if (p < 0) {
        p = p + incE;
      } else {
        y = y + stepy;
        p = p + incNE;
      }
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
  } else {
    p = 2 * dx - dy;
    incE = 2 * dx;
    incNE = 2 * (dx - dy);
    while (y != y1) {
      y = y + stepy;
      if (p < 0) {
        p = p + incE;
      } else {
        x = x + stepx;
        p = p + incNE;
      }
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
  }
}

var paint = document.getElementById('painting');
var ctx = paint.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
Bresenham(ctx, 30, 10, 120, 90);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="painting"></canvas>
```

Te dibuja una línea pero compuesta de puntos.

Comment: Gracias, es una buena opción, pero quiero hacer esto en WebGL por fines educativos.

Comment: @JosephAlbertoMorthimerLeon El webgl que trae el canvas del HTML usa tres dimensiones. El algoritmo que propones solo usa dos por lo tanto el contexto correcto a escoger sería `2d` en lugar de `webgl`. Como manejarías tú las coordenadas del eje Z faltante?

Comment: Haciendo que las coordenadas Z sean 0

Comment: este mismo algoritmo se puede usar para la circunferencia y para el movimiento del balon de juegos como ser ping pong